Creating sparse models
Lately, I read a comment by Erwin Kalvelagen that there have been efforts to develop "tricks" to transform dense optimization models to sparse models. One of these tricks is e.g. replacing a variable with more than one other variables. Is anyone aware of a publication where such tricks are mentioned?

@erwin-kalvelagen would be the best

Can you be a bit more specific?
